# In Canvas tag Game.draw() function wont run?

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';

var Game = {
    canvas: undefined, 
    canvasContext: undefined
};

Game.start = function () {
    Game.canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    Game.canvasContext = Game.canvas.getContext('2d');
    Game.mainLoop();
    
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Game.start);

Game.update = function () {
};

Game.draw = function () {
    Game.canvasContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
    Game.canvasContext.fillReact(0, 0, Game.canvas.width, Game.canvas.height);
};

Game.mainLoop = function () {
    Game.update();
    Game.draw();
    window.setTimeout(mainLoop, 1000 / 60);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>FlyingSprite</title>
    <script src="FlyingSprite.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gameArea">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Above code should set the colour of 'canvas' to blue, but the code won't run . Function 'Game.draw()' is most likely the problem, if anyone is willing to take the time to help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `fillReact`?  Maybe you mean `fillRect`.  You need to provide more info about the problem you are getting "the code won't run" is not particularly descriptive.  If you're seeing an error include the error message in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have `Game.canvasContext.fillReact` instead of `Game.canvasContext.fillRect`.

You'll also want to pass `Game.mainLoop` into `window.setTimeout` instead of just `mainLoop`, as `window.setTimeout(Game.mainLoop, 1000 / 60);`. Having said that, you're probably actually looking for `window.setInterval()` rather than `window.setTimeout()` - the difference being that **[`.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** will loop repeatedly, whereas **[`.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)** will only fire once.

Here's an updated sample:

```js
'use strict';

var Game = {
    canvas: undefined, 
    canvasContext: undefined
};

Game.start = function () {
    Game.canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    Game.canvasContext = Game.canvas.getContext('2d');
    Game.mainLoop();
    
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Game.start);

Game.update = function () {
};

Game.draw = function () {
    Game.canvasContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
    Game.canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, Game.canvas.width, Game.canvas.height);
};

Game.mainLoop = function () {
    Game.update();
    Game.draw();
    window.setInterval(Game.mainLoop, 1000 / 60);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>FlyingSprite</title>
    <script src="FlyingSprite.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gameArea">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, a simple problem. Next time, I make sure to find these small problems on my own. And make sure not to waste anyones time, thanks.